# C# Keys Enumeration Confused: Keys.Alt or Keys.RButton | Keys.ShiftKey | Keys.Alt

Tags: c#, enums

I was trying to test whether the Alt key was pressed.

I had a check similar to:

```
private void ProcessCmdKey(Keys keyData)
{
 if (keyData == Keys.Alt)
 {
  System.Console.WriteLine ("Alt Key Pressed");
 } 
}
```

Anyways needless to say when I breakpointed when I had pressed the Alt key the debugger told me the key that was pressed was actually Keys.RButton | Keys.ShiftKey | Keys.Alt

Can anyone shed some light on what is going on or perhaps point me to an article that can explain?

Thanks
FZ

Edit:
I am still a bit lost as to why the ENUM would have have other bit values set and not simply the Alt key? I understand that the enum can include more than 1 state with the flags attrivbute but I am not sure why it does if all I pressed was Alt?

Comment: I'm curious why those flags are always set, too. Seems like a bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to test whether `Alt` is *part* of the pressed keys, you can perform a bitwise test;

```
if((keyData & Keys.Alt) == Keys.Alt) {...}
```

Comment: Which is better from a coding perspective? == Keys.Alt or != 0?

Comment: "== Keys.Alt" is the best form. In any case where the value (Keys.Alt in this case) is not a single bit value, the !=0 test will give false positives. Although in this cae there is no difference, it is better practice to be precise so that you never get caught out by a case where !=0 will fail.

Comment: P.S. The cleanest way is actually to implement a library method that encapsulates this test in a human-readable and easily typed form. It's easy to type && or | when you meant &. Using if (IsBitSet(keyData, Keys.Alt)) is more readable and less error prone.

Comment: @Jason good idea. Check out the functions below http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369312/c-keys-enumeration-confused-keys-alt-or-keys-rbutton-keys-shiftkey-keys-alt/2033796#2033796

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question. And I'm very curious about knowing that!

Comment: @ÁxelCostasPena can you be specific about how it doesn't answer it?

Comment: Title: "C# Keys Enumeration Confused: Keys.Alt or Keys.RButton | Keys.ShiftKey | Keys.Alt". Body resume: "Anyways needless to say when I breakpointed when I had pressed the Alt key the debugger told me the key that was pressed was actually Keys.RButton | Keys.ShiftKey | Keys.Alt. Can anyone shed some light on what is going on or perhaps point me to an article that can explain?" The phenomenon of the ghost keypresses hasn´t been explained, only a workaround provided.

Comment: Is the confusing part that Microsoft did not use powers of two for each of the Keys?  For example the Enter key enum is 13.  Which shows in the debugger as LButton | MButton | Back (1 + 4 + 8).

Answer (score 4):

Keys is a [Flags Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229062.aspx).  This means it can have more than one value at a given time.  You should check it like so:

```
if ( (keyData & Keys.Alt) == Keys.Alt)
{
   // Alt was pressed!
}
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the OP's question

Comment: @ÁxelCostasPena Not sure I agree - it explains why the issue exists, and shows how to check for it correctly.  What else do you want?

Comment: Title: "C# Keys Enumeration Confused: Keys.Alt or Keys.RButton | Keys.ShiftKey | Keys.Alt". Body resume: "Anyways needless to say when I breakpointed when I had pressed the Alt key the debugger told me the key that was pressed was actually Keys.RButton | Keys.ShiftKey | Keys.Alt. Can anyone shed some light on what is going on or perhaps point me to an article that can explain?" The phenomenon of the ghost keypresses hasn´t been explained, only a workaround provided.

Comment: @ÁxelCostasPena The phenomenon is exactly what I posted - it's a flags enum, which means that it turns on Alt, but also that it was the right alt button, etc.

Comment: I am still not understanding why a flag ShiftKey is being set when I just press Alt. And I think the OP's scenario is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Enum with FlagsAttribute are implemented using bits.
See this link for a good start - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx

EDIT: Are you pressing RIGHT (mouse button) with Shift key during the operation, to select/highlight something, while debugging?

Comment: I am still a bit lost as to why the ENUM would have have other bit values set and not simply the Alt key?

I understand that the enum can include more than 1 state but I am not sure why it does if all I pressed was Alt?

Comment: Nope. I had simply placed the breakpoint at the start of the method and hit the ALT key.

Comment: I have to add that I am using a 3rd party GUI toolkit, so there may be a chance they are adding to the key to be processed, but i hope they aren't.

Comment: Assuming you don't add code to handle ALT, will the control take some action when you press ALT?

Comment: Remove the breakpoint & put statement like Console.WriteLine(Keys) to see what it has to say?

Answer (score 1):

Mark's technique ([the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850/c-and-arrow-keys/2033811#2033811)) works for modifier keys, but it caught me by surprise that some keys (e.g. arrows) are combinations of bits, and won't work. For example the following test turns out to be true:

```
((Keys.Right & Keys.Left) == Keys.Left)
```

I have [posted some useful little functions for key handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850/c-and-arrow-keys/2033811#2033811) on a related StackOverflow post regarding arrow key handling.